# Couldn't find MSVC toolchain in eclipse though Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 is installed

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I want to build a static library using MSVC compiler. And I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and it is functional. But I haven't found any toolchain or compiler for MSVC in eclipse project properties so that I can build the static library for windows. Gone through several links. But no luck.

I want to know how I can get MSVC as compiler or toolchain in the compiler/toolchain option of eclipse project properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is solved. I am posting the solution so that if anyone faces the same problem, then it would help them.

The probable root cause was, I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and was running Eclipse Kepler CDT. And this version of eclipse CDT doesn't recognize MSVC2012.

After installing the latest eclipse CDT which is Eclipse Mars, it discovered the toolchain for Visual C++ successfully and worked fine.

So, I would suggest to use [Eclipse Mars](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/marsm3) for avoiding these types of situations.